# Updating the next element in list based on the value from current element

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have one list `List<CT>` need to update the same `List<CT>` in a single pass using stream.

We have two quantity fields, if the `firstQty` is less than the `secondQty` the remaining should be set to the `secondQty` in the next record. We do this calculation only if the `currentMonth` indicator is true;

Input:

```
none
[CT(currentMonth=tue, firstQty=600, secondQty=620,..),           
 CT(currentMonth=false, firstQty=0, secondQty=0,..),        
 CT(currentMonth=false, firstQty=0, secondQty=0,..)]
```

Output:

```
none
[CT(currentMonth=tue, firstQty=600, secondQty=620,..),           
 CT(currentMonth=false, firstQty=0, secondQty=20,..),        
 CT(currentMonth=false, firstQty=0, secondQty=0,..)]
```

```
class CT {       
   Boolean currentMonth;      
   BigDecimal firstQty;      
   BigDecimal secondQty;       
}
```

```
        List<CT> lotsDetailsTpm =  deals.stream()
                .map(dcl ->{
                    BigDecimal diffrence = BigDecimal.ZERO;
                    if(dcl.getCurrentMonth()) {
                        BigDecimal qtyFirst = deals.getFirstQty();
                        BigDecimal qtySecond = deals.getSecondQty();
                        BigDecimal diff = qtySecond.subtract(qtyFirst);
                        dcl.qtySecond(qtySecond.sbtract(diff));
                        if(diff.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 1) {
                            //need to update the diff to the next element
                        }
                    }
                    return dcl;
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here the difficulty is how to keep the difference in the quantity and use the value to update the next element.

Comment: Don’t use streams for this. They are not suited for a task that involves such operations between elements.

Comment: And please add your current solution attempt.

Comment: A solution would be to use an `IntStream` and loop through your collection as you would do in a more classical "for loop" (something like `IntStream.range(0, collection.size()).forEach(i -> \*do your operations here*\);`). However, I can't see any point in doing so: just do a "for loop", it will be easier to read.

Comment: @Abrikot: It's just an abuse of [tag:java-stream]. I'd stick with for-loop then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the behavior of [`Stream::reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) which works with two subsequent values.

- `<U> U reduce(U identity, BiFunction<U,? super T,U> accumulator, BinaryOperator<U> combiner)`

The code:

```
AList<CT> newList = list.stream().reduce(
    new ArrayList<>(),                             // ArrayList as identity, the storage
    (l, ct) -> {                                   // List and the next CT
        if (l.isEmpty()) {                         // ... if the list is empty, insert CT
            l.add(ct);
        } else if (ct.getCurrentMonth()) {         // .. or else do you calculation
            final CT other = l.get(l.size() - 1);
            final BigDecimal diff = other.getSecondQty().subtract(other.getFirstQty());
            if (diff.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0) {
                ct.setSecondQty(diff);
            }
            l.add(ct);                             // .. add the new item
        }
        return l;                                  // .. and return the whole list
    },
    (l, r) -> l                                    // Finally, the operator returns the list
);
```

The solution is not optimal (luckily, it doesn't use any removal methods, only getting), but is working. Remember [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) is not suitable for such processing, the good old for-loop would be better since you can comfortably control the indices in the loop.

Finally, as far as I understand from your question, the 3<sup>rd</sup> item should also have the `secondQty` as `20` since `20-0=20` of the the 2<sup>nd</sup>. Maybe I misunderstood, however, it is not important and easily to be amended. You get the idea with `Stream::reduce` and feel free to apply it to your problem.

```
CT(currentMonth=false, firstQty=0, secondQty=20,..)
```